# Ordering in Ruby Pathname .children

Tags: ruby, sorting, pathname

It seems the order of the filesystem entities returned by Pathname's `.children` method is arbitrary or at least not alphabetical.

Is there a way to have these returned in alphabetical order via the file system rather than calling `.sort` on the returned array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pathname's [`children`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-children) is actually doing:

```
def children(with_directory=true)
  with_directory = false if @path == '.'
  result = []
  Dir.foreach(@path) {|e|
    next if e == '.' || e == '..'
    if with_directory
      result << self.class.new(File.join(@path, e))
    else
      result << self.class.new(e)
    end
  }
  result
end
```

[`Dir.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) calls the OS and iterates the directory passed in. There is no provision for telling the OS to sort by a particular order.

"[What is the "directory order" of files in a directory (used by `ls -U`)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13451/2071)" is probably of interest to you.

Comment: While I appreciate the vote and all, please read the last paragraph in http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I find that a strange policy. I've never had a mental link between an accepted answer and gratitude for that answer :)

Comment: It's not strange when you understand the goal of SO. It's not a discussion forum and chit-chat/back and forth via comments is discouraged because they're for clarification and recommendations. There are other mechanisms available for that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following if you want to simply sort on names of files

```
Dir.children("./DIR_NAME/").sort
```

Comment: This is a strange answer as the question specifically asks if there is a way other than just calling `sort` on the array returned by `children()`.